# sql set variable using COUNT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a simple query to my server and want the result to be stored in the variable @times.

```
DECLARE @times int

SET @times = SELECT COUNT(DidWin)as "I Win"
FROM thetable
WHERE DidWin = 1 AND Playername='Me'
```

IntelliSense says `Wrong syntax near Select`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You just need parentheses around your select:

```
SET @times = (SELECT COUNT(DidWin) FROM ...)
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
SELECT @times = COUNT(DidWin) FROM ...
```

Answer (score 13):

You can select directly into the variable rather than using set:

```
DECLARE @times int

SELECT @times = COUNT(DidWin)
FROM thetable
WHERE DidWin = 1 AND Playername='Me'
```

If you need to set multiple variables you can do it from the same select (example a bit contrived):

```
DECLARE @wins int, @losses int

SELECT @wins = SUM(DidWin), @losses = SUM(DidLose)
FROM thetable
WHERE Playername='Me'
```

If you are partial to using set, you can use parentheses:

```
DECLARE @wins int, @losses int

SET (@wins, @losses) = (SELECT SUM(DidWin), SUM(DidLose)
FROM thetable
WHERE Playername='Me');
```

Comment: You can but you don't **need** to select directly into the variable.

Comment: @ypercube: But if you get in the habit of using select, you wont try to use 2 or more set + select commands when 1 select can set all the variables at once. I also find the SELECT to be more readable.

Comment: I disagree on the readability but that's personal taste. Readable for me would be `SET (@var1, @var2, ..., @varn) = (SELECT ... )`

Comment: I like that the assignment is close the the variable name. If you have *many* assignments, it could be harder to pick out which item in the select applies to which variable. Not to mention that you end up having more code.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
DECLARE @times int

SELECT @times =  COUNT(DidWin)
FROM thetable
WHERE DidWin = 1 AND Playername='Me'
```

You also don't need the 'as' clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT` as **lambacck** said 
or add parentheses:

```
SET @times = (SELECT COUNT(DidWin)as "I Win"
FROM thetable
WHERE DidWin = 1 AND Playername='Me');
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to print the result with column name "c", or read the result in your code by using "c" column name:

```
DECLARE @c int;
SELECT c = count(*) from '%Table%' WHERE '%condition%'
```

Comment: This will not assign the result to the variable.  It will instead return a result set with a column named c.  The variable @c would be null.  And you can't assign and return in a single statement.